# Do inline functions retain their context within the function they are inlined within

Tags: c++

If I create a function which is declared as inline, and use that within another function, if the function is inlined (which may not happen, as inline is optional for the compiler), would that function retain it's own context scope?

i.e. would the inlined function's stack variables disappear from the stack at the end of the inserted inlined function, or after the function it has been inserted into has been taken off the stack?

Comment: It's definitely its own scope and from the C++-side of things is a completely separate function. What you're wondering about is more of an implementation detail. A reasonable compiler would probably handle it like it does any other local variables in a nested scope, I guess.

Comment: You don't really need to think about it. From your perspective, the scope, the stack, variable names etc. are still all treated as if it's a regular function.

All `inline` means in practice is that the function definition has to be known at compile time, nothing more.

Comment: The compiler has to guarantee that it behaves "as-if" it was a regular function call. Beyond that, it can use whatever optimizations it wants.

Comment: The C/C++ `inline` and function inlining are two different things. `inline` does not mean the function should be inlined, it's not even a hint. `inline` means the definition is provided inline, in a header for example. It can be used to remove ODR errors. Of course, since the definition is provided inline, it is a good candidate for inlining optimization.

Comment: Yes, I also assumed that it would retain its own context. I'm reviewing some code and someone has tried to inline a function with a lock in it, with the intention that the lock would protect the rest of the code. Which seemed a bit dangerous to me - considering that inlining is optional, but I hadn't thought about whether inlining would keep its context.

Comment: @ElderBug you're wrong there. Functions declared inline do need to be inline for inline to work. But you don't need to use the inline reserved word to make an inline function and it is indeed a hint, as described by ISO C++ https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions. I was hoping to get a formal reference for the answers to this, if possible.

Comment: No I'm not wrong. `inline` changes the compiler behavior. You DO need the keyword in some situation. For example if you have a function defined in a header, and used in multiple C++ files, it won't compile at all without `inline`. It really has little to do with optimisations. In gcc you can declare a function `inline __attribute__ ((noinline))` and it will work as expected : defined inline but with inlining opt disabled. And this inlining optimisation is not triggered by `inline`. You can use `static` instead and get the same optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not stack variables exist outside their scope is not "observable behavior". That is, a conforming program cannot detect whether their memory still exists. So, under the "as if" rule, the compiler is free to leave the memory their, reuse it for some other variable, or pop the stack. Your program can't tell, and all three of those can be seen if you look at the generated machine code.

Even without inlining the compiler will often play with memory in ways that might not be obvious.

```
void f() {
    int a = get_a_value();
    call_a_function(a);
    int b = get_b_value();
    call_another_function(b);
}
```

Here, chances are good that when you compile with optimizations, the compiler will use the same memory location for `a` and `b`. Formally they have the same lifetime, but their actual uses do not overlap, so there's no need for separate memory locations. (And, yes, it's also possible that the compiler would just stuff the data into a register rather than using memory).

Again: if your program can't tell the difference, the compiler can do whatever makes sense for the hardware and OS.

Comment: Right, that was an example to explain the question, rather than the exact situation. What if that inline function had side effects. In fact a lock - yes, I know, no one would do that. But that would avoid those other compiler optimisations and have a side effect.

Comment: @Alex -- side effects are observable behavior, so the "as if" rule doesn't allow the compiler to omit them. But that's not about whether or when stack variables disappear; it's about when the code that does the lock and unlock gets called.